# Get site feed posts as search results

Tags: search

So i have the usual search box on the site which i use for search.
I have also put a site feed web part on this site.

Is it possible to set up the searchbox to also search for site feed posts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I believe this is possible. The Result Type for the feed posts is `SharePoint MicroBlog Post`.

If you have an Enterprise Search Centre provisioned, these results will usually show under the 'Conversations' tab after 'Discussions'